# AJAX JSON C# used to make Pie Chart Dynamic?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

```
    function Piee() {
        $('#Pie').parent().find('.loding_box_outer').show().fadeIn();
        var startdate = '2017/1/10';
        var val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 = null;
        var emp = 20;
        myData = "{ 'date':'" + startdate + "', 'Level1':'" + val1 + "','Level2':' " + val2 + "','Level3':'" + val3 + "','Level4':'" + val4 + "','Level5':'" + val5 + "','Level6':'" + val6 + "', 'EmployeeId':'" + emp + "'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../NewDashboard.asmx/PIECHART",
            data: myData,
            async:false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: drawChart,
            //    function (data) {

            //    var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            //    var jsondata = [];
            //    $.each(json, function(i, serial){
            //        for(var i in serial)
            //        {
            //            var array_need = new Array(i, parseFloat(serial[i]));
            //            jsondata.push(array_need);
            //        }


            //    });
            //    drawChart(jsondata);
            //},
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error Found");
            }
        });
    }

    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart(data)
    {
        //alert(data);
        var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        //var list = json;
        //alert(json);
       // var jsondata = ['One', 'two', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'];
        var jsondata = ['One', 'two','three','four','five','six','seven'];
      //  alert(jsondata);
        //$.each(json, function (i, serial) {
         // alert(serial);
          //for (var i in jsondata) {
              //alert(jsondata)
                //var array_need = new Array(i, parseFloat(jsondata[i]));
              //alert(array_need)
                //jsondata.push(array_need);
              //alert(jsondata)
            //}
        //$.each(json, function(i, serial)
        //{

                      for(var i in jsondata)
                      {
                          var serie = [];
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].two);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].three);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].four);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].five);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].six);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].seven);
                          series.push(jsondata[i].One);
                         serie.push(parseFloat(jsondata));
                          alert(serie);
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                          //jsondata.push(json[i].One)
                         // alert(json);
                        // var array_need = new Array(i, parseFloat(jsondata[i]));
                          //var array_need = new Array( parseFloat(json[i]));
                         // jsondata.push(array_need);
                          //alert(array_need);
                      }

    //});


        //$.each(list, function (i, table) {

            //for (var i in json)
            // {
            //var serie = [];
            //jsondata.push(json[i].PLANNEDVISITS);
            //jsondata.push(json[i].One);
            //jsondata.push(parseFloat(serie));
           // alert(jsondata);
            //alert(serie);
            //jsondata.push(table[i].PLANNED);
            //alert(jsondata);
            //jsondata.push(parseFloat(serie));
            //alert(jsondata);

            //}
        //);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
            (jsondata);

        var options = {
            title: 'Planned Visit'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Pie'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string PIECHART(string date, string Level1, string Level2, string Level3, string Level4, string Level5, string Level6, string EmployeeId)
{
           JavaScriptSerializer _jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = string.Empty;
            string r = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                #region Initialize

                var PieChart = new System.Data.DataSet();
                _nvCollection.Clear();
                PieChart.Clear();
                int year = 0, month = 0;

                double employeeId = 0;

                if (Level6 != "0")
                {
                    employeeId = Convert.ToInt64(EmployeeId);
                }
                else
                {
                    employeeId = 0;
                }

                #endregion

                #region Set Year + Month

                if (date != "")
                {
                    year = Convert.ToDateTime(date).Year;
                    month = Convert.ToDateTime(date).Month;
                }
                else
                {
                    year = DateTime.Now.Year;
                    month = DateTime.Now.Month;
                }

                #endregion

                #region Filter By Role

                //_nvCollection.Add("@Level3id-int", Level3.ToString());
                //_nvCollection.Add("@Level4id-int", Level4.ToString());
                //_nvCollection.Add("@Level5id-int", Level5.ToString());
                //_nvCollection.Add("@Level6id-int", Level6.ToString());
                _nvCollection.Add("@EmpId-int", EmployeeId.ToString());
                _nvCollection.Add("@Month-int", Convert.ToString(month));
                _nvCollection.Add("@Year-int", Convert.ToString(year));

                PieChart = GetData("sp_PlannedVisits", _nvCollection);


                #endregion

                if (PieChart != null)
                {
                    if (PieChart.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        r = PieChart.Tables[0].ToJsonString();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
         //   return r;
           return result = _jss.Serialize(r);
        }
```

this is my code for displaying dynamic data coming from stored procedure into a pie chart. The webservice is being hit properly but i am unable to display the pie chart because of drawchart(data) function. 
i had tried everything u can. Answer will be appreciated.